# VSCode jest runner runs all test when trying to run a single test

Tags: vscode-extensions, ts-jest, jes

So i have my `jest.config.ts` set to look for tests in my project using `testMatch: ['/__tests__/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'],`

My folder structure looks like this

```
src
   __tests__
   features
       __tests__
           App.test.tsx
           feature1.test.tsx
```

I am trying to run say a feature1test1 which lies inside `feature1.test.tsx`. Whenever i try to run just a single test, it runs all the test from App.test.tsx as well as feature1.test.tsx

How do i run a single test and also do the same from the testing tab in vscode